# How do I restore power to living room receptacles?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, gfci

I removed a data receptacle from my living room, and all the outlets to that room (the alarm system) and garage door are not working.  After trying to diagnose the problem I’m left very puzzled!

- the receptacle has two different data cables and one Romex cable
- Data cables are both white,green,blue,orange, white/green
- Romex is green,black,red,yellow.
- nothing is tripped in the box
- testing 120v on every breaker with a Volt meter
- the receptacles that aren’t working are reading 0volts
- all GFCI in the entire house have been reset and are working

1. Is it possible one of the GFCIs is defective even though the outlet itself works?
2. Does disconnected data cables have anything to do with loosing power to the entire room?

[image]

Comment: what were those data cables for, did you just cut them off or disconected from what ?

Comment: Why do you have a garage door in your living room?  Are your electric(120v) outlets working or not?  Is it only your low voltage(alarm, door bell,data) that stop working?

Comment: "all the outlets to that room (the alarm system) and garage door are not working." All the _data_ outlets or all the 120v _power_ outlets are not working. You've shown us a picture of low-voltage wiring, not 120V household AC wiring.

Comment: Can you show us a picture of the "data receptacle" that you removed?  I'm not familiar with any one "receptacle" that would have all these wires connected to it.  Can you show us a picture of the receptacles that are no longer working also?   And explain why you "removed" it .... when you appear to have also disconnected a bunch of wires without knowing what they are.  The obvious answer would be to reconnect them.  Did you note how they were connected before?   A LOT more info is needed here.

Comment: @Ruskes They’re for a landline I’m assuming.  I just sniped them off and didn’t take a picture of the wiring before removing it.

Comment: @crip659. I have a garage door in my garage (which is the next room over).  All the 120v outlets and light switches in the garage and living room aren’t working.

Comment: @FreeMan Thanks!  That’s helpful to know the 4 cable black red green yellow cable is low voltage

Comment: Those data/low voltage cables and the house's electric system should be separated when put in.  It is possible if you pulled on those data cables, they caught a power cable and loosen/broke a connection or both just happen at the same time.  What were the data cables for?  Is it possible one or more controlled a relay/smart thingy?

Comment: **ALL** the cables/wires you've shown us in this picture are low voltage. The one on the right with the white/cream sheath looks like POTS phone wire. The two on the left look to be newer (they have some cord in them to improve bend/break resistance, and the colors _look_ different), but they're still LV wiring. Probably for the alarm system.

Comment: Those are way too small to be Romex cable.  Romex starts at 14 AWG. Those like like #26 to #20 AWG.  (you can look up what that means). Also Romex has a **bare** ground and a white insulated wire.  Looks like ethernet and phone.  None of which are legal to be mixed with AC power in the same box. (unless there is a dividing wall in the box).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Romex is a brand name, but commonly used to refer to NM (non-metallic) sheathed multi-conductor cable for 120V/240V wiring.

What you have in the picture are 3 low voltage (i.e., telephone and/or networking) cables. Red/Green/Black/Yellow is extremely common for 2-pair telephone cable (Red/green for the first pair, black/yellow for the second pair, used for either two phone lines or a phone system with one pair for voice and one for control signals).

So none of that is what is commonly referred to as "Romex", and none of that should have anything to do with your 120V circuits. The insulation is almost certainly not rated for 120V, and the wires are way to small for even a basic 15A circuit. In addition, low voltage cables (phone, network, cable TV, burglar alarm, etc.) are never supposed to be in the same boxes, conduits, etc. as 120V circuits.

My best guess is that you have a loose connection somewhere *near* the data receptacle that you worked on, and now it has come apart, breaking the circuit. But it is also possible that it is a coincidence and totally unrelated.

GFCI is often a factor, but if a GFCI receptacle works then anything connected by the LOAD terminals should work as well. Possibilities (GFCI or not) include:

- Loose screw connection
- Bad backstab (and if you find one, replace the receptacle or at least move the wires to screw terminals)
- Loose wire nut
- Mouse chewed through a cable (evidence will include a dead toasted mouse)
- Flipped switch - a switch can control a receptacle or a whole chain of receptacles. Not generally recommended, but stranger things have happened.

Keep hunting. And along the way, make a map of your circuits for the next time.

Comment: Thanks!!  I thought the black,red,green,yellow was for delivering power.  (I was confused why all three were connected to one Ethernet receptacle). I’ll start digging a little deeper, appreciate the thorough response!

Comment: It ended up being a faulty GFCI in the garage - Thanks again for all the information.